# Intellisense & Strongly Typed Data Controls - no more typos...?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, webforms, visual-studio-2012

I was reading up on the ASP.NET 4.5 Web Form features to see what is new.  I recently tried out the **strongly typed data controls** feature by using a GridView.  However, as far as I can tell, you can only use the strongly-typed benefit when you are using a **asp:TemplateField**..... like this:

```
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" >
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Item.Name.ToString() %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
```

Is that really true?  You can't use strong-typing with asp:BoundField, asp:DynamicField or any of the other possible column controls in a GridView??
For example, when I put a standard asp:BoundField it didn't provide me with any intellisense auto-completion.  I could only type out a string for the DataField attribute.  Like so:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="JyooobTitle" HeaderText="Job Title" />
```

Oops!  Looks like I mispelled "JobTitle" there, *but the compiler didn't catch it*.  So in order to benefit from the strong typing, it would seem I am forced into using the TemplateField option.... for every single column whether I need it or not!

Furthermore, if you want to put a SortExpression attribute on your TemplateField....  you have to hope you spell that one right as well, because it doesn't appear you get strong-typing their either.  Hopefully I am just missing something obvious, because this is a great new feature, but it sure seems like it was **only half-implemented**.

Can anyone verify if this is true... or if I am missing something?

Comment: I can verify that this is true in VS2010. Even ReSharper (v7.1) does not help.

Comment: Has anyone figured out how to use model binding for the `SortExpression` of the `TemplateField` control? Alternatively, can I specify a method whose return value should be used as the sort expression?

Answer (score 1):

As a relatively new ASP.NET developer, I probably don't have the insight or experience to know the full answer to this question, but I will give my best understanding of the issue. I too have used the ASP.net 4.5 "strongly typed model binding". When I first discovered it via Scott Hanselman's excellent [video](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-web-forms/aspnet-45-web-forms-strong-typed-data-controls) it blew my mind. The issue you mention is definitely an unfortunate limitation of the feature. However, I think that we should be thankful for the help we do get.

Consider your other work in the `.aspx` page. While Intellisense does provide some help filling control attributes (e.g. true/false dropdown for `Visible=`), validation of the declarative markup is, overall, quite minimal. This is part of it's very nature. It's not a 'programming' document but rather a semantic document. By virtue of this fact it can be changed without recompiling the project, which can be very convenient at times.

ASP.NET does provide a method for placing actual compiled code in the aspx markup, via the in-line code sections (<%# %>, etc.) The strongly typed binding takes advantage of these. They're like a back door into programming world and give you the full Intellisense experience.

I expect that we may some day see strong typing in the `DataField` attribute, but I wouldn't look for it any time too soon. For right now I'll take advantage of `ItemType` and rejoice in its convenience any time I can.

Comment: I agree it is a great addition.  Just wish it had been more fully implemented.  The way it is advertised had me expecting more - specifically that all the types of fields you could put into a GridView would be supported... BoundField, ButtonField, CheckBoxField, CommandField, HyperLinkField, ImageField.

But when I actually tried it out.... it seems that only TemplateField is supported.

Comment: You definitely have a point - this feature is not as useful in a GridView. However, using it with one of the free text data controls, such as a Repeater or FormView, helps to show off its power.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I worked around the sort expression binding problem.

Instead of setting `SortExpression` to a real property name, I set it to the column's ordinal position.

```
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name" SortExpression="1" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Item.Name %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Job Title" SortExpression="2" >
        <ItemTemplate>
            <%# Item.JobTitle %>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Then, attach a handler to the gridview's `Sorting` event.

```
<asp:GridView runat="server"
              OnSorting="Sorting"
              ...
```

One of the event arguments is the sort expression that you defined earlier (i.e. `"1"` or `"2"`). You can use this value to programmatically re-bind the sort expression to an actual property name.

**Note**: following this approach means giving up automatic switching between ascending/descending sort order. It's not particularly difficult to re-implement it though.

**Note**: I'm using a reflection-based approach to determine the property names at execution-time.

```
protected void Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    int columnPosition;
    if (!int.TryParse(e.SortExpression, out columnPosition))
    {
        return;
    }

    switch (columnPosition)
    {
        case 1:
            e.SortExpression = Reflector.GetPropertyName<Employee>(o => o.Name);
            break;

        case 2:
            e.SortExpression = Reflector.GetPropertyName<Employee>(o => o.JobTitle);
            break;
    }

    var grid = (GridView)sender;
    if (grid.SortExpression == e.SortExpression)
    {
        if (grid.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            e.SortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
        }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my code for the `Reflector` class that I'm using in the example above.

```
/// <summary>Utility class. Provides static reflection-based utility methods.</summary>
public static class Reflector
{
    #region Public Methods and Operators

    /// <summary>Gets the name of the property that is accessed by the given expression. Usage: <c>Reflector.GetPropertyName&lt;MyClass&gt;(obj =&gt; obj.MyProperty);</c></summary>
    /// <param name="selectorExpression">The expression that selects the property of which the name should be returned.</param>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type that defines the property.</typeparam>
    /// <returns>The name of the property.</returns>
    public static string GetPropertyName<T>(Expression<Func<T, object>> selectorExpression) where T : class
    {
        MemberExpression memberExpression;
        var unaryExpression = selectorExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        if (unaryExpression != null)
        {
            memberExpression = unaryExpression.Operand as MemberExpression;
        }
        else
        {
            memberExpression = selectorExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
        }

        if (memberExpression == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        return memberExpression.Member.Name;
    }

    #endregion
}
```